# Getting particular object

Tags: php, json, laravel

> "data":
>   "{\"thread\":{\"user_id\":76,\"parent_id\":\"139\",\"item_id\":\"178\",\"comment\":\"s\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-09-18
>   15:19:24\",\"created_at\":\"2017-09-18
>   15:19:24\",\"id\":140},\"user\":{\"id\":76,\"name\":\"Kavi\",\"lastname\":\"Arasan\",\"mobile\":\"822-034-1179\",\"email\":\"kayalmanimohana@gmail.com\",\"verified\":0,\"email_token\":\"1ATrlUoyWy\",\"created_at\":\"2017-09-15
>   16:47:59\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-09-18
>   15:18:57\",\"address\":null,\"city\":null,\"state\":null,\"country\":null,\"pin\":null,\"profile\":null,\"gender\":null,\"street_num\":null,\"provider\":null,\"provider_id\":null,\"is_delete\":null,\"username\":\"dummy\"}}",

i have data object like this in my db. How do i get the user id present within thread of data? Am using laravel

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is just data. You haven't even specified any technology that needs to be used. How is anyone supposed to help?

Comment: Am using laravel

Comment: OK, I have submitted an edit to change your tags.

Comment: Although this is still too broad of a question. Please do some research, show some effort and code and ask more specific questions to it.

Comment: That's what you get for using a relational DB to store serialised data. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kayal if you are still learning then this is good but sometime you should read the documentation

here is the method that you can do this easily

> For Example

Assuming Table name `test`

```
+------------+
| id |  data |
+------------+
| 1  | {...} |
+------------+
```

**suppose you have Model `Test.php`**

Then add a protected property `$casts` it is an array in this array add `key => value` **key** is column name and value will be in which type you want to cast like object or array in this case i am using object.

```
namespace App;

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $casts = ['data' => 'object']; // add this property
```

**in your controller**

in this case i am using `TestController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Test;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function seeUserId()
    {
        $test = Test::find(1); // or your query
        $user_id = $test->data->thread->user_id; // you can access like this this is only example
    }


    public function saveData($data)
    {
        $test = new Test;
        $test->data = $data; // don't use json_encode() just pass any object or array ;
        $test->save();
    }
```

laravel doc :- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Answer (score 0):

> foreach ($unread as $unr) {
>               $data = json_decode($unr->data,true);
>               $user_id = $data['thread']['user_id'];
>           }

This made it possible